# SQL Alchemy order_by with case

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to do a query where one row should always come first and otherwise ordered ascending or descending.
I'm using SQLAlchemy ORM.

```
the_case = case([(table.name != "foo", table.name)], else_="")

a = db.query(table).order_by(the_case, asc(table.name)).all()
b = db.query(table).order_by(the_case, desc(table.name)).all()
```

It works except a == b

Answer (score 0):

I know it might be a bit too late but try to use `the_case` as an argument for `asc()` and `desc()`:

```
a = db.query(table).order_by(asc(the_case)).all()
b = db.query(table).order_by(desc(the_case)).all()
```